# How to remove slash (/) from url hash

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

On my SP site, I'm sending some queries with URL to filter data,

```
https://microsoft.sharepoint.com/teams/sitename/page.aspx?queryTags=#tag1,tag2
```

Few months back it was working fine, but now url generating `Slash (/)` between `?queryTags#` and `tags`,

```
https://microsoft.sharepoint.com/teams/sitename/page.aspx?queryTags=#/tag1,tag2
```

now filter data function is not working because of that extra `/`. How can I remove that slash from URL,

I can't make changes in filter date function because it's containing tons of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace string with javascript with replace function

```
 url.replace("#/", "#")
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: But if you use JavaScript for replace then above code will replace only for first occurrence in string. So if "#/" is multiple time then it will not work.

Comment: I'm sending replace queries in filter function and this trick worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code to solve your problem:

```
var _pageUrl=document.URL;//page URL

JSRequest.EnsureSetup();
var _queryTags = JSRequest.QueryString["queryTags"]; //QueryString

_queryTags = replaceAll(_queryTags,"//",""); //Replacing '/' with empty space

//reusable function for replace all
function replaceAll(str, find, replace) {
  return str.replace(new RegExp(find, 'g'), replace);
}
```